# Fire an event when Collection Changed (add or remove)

Tags: c#, events

I have a class which contains a list :

```
public class a
{
    private List<MyType> _Children;

    public Children
    {
        get { return(_Children); }
        set { _Children = value ; }
    }
}
```

I want to create an event and fire it whenever my list (_Children here) is changed for example an item is added to it or removed from it or it's cleared.

thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Change your list to an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).  It implements [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), so you can subscribe to change events on it.

Another option is to use [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx), if you need full list semantics.

Comment: One thing to remember about ObservableCollection is it will throw an exception if you try to add an element to it from thread other than the one you created it on (whether or not you lock on it).

Answer (score 3):

See [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to control the Add and remove methods and raise event, check `Collection<T>` out.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx